# How do I politely remind the COO of a company to respond to my previous email?

Tags: professionalism, email

I am expected to join their company in the next few days. It's a small company of about 50 people and there is no formal HR department. I've been communicating directly with the COO so far.

There has been a change in my schedule and I'll be able to join the new company 1 month later than I had anticipated. I sent her an email on Friday @ 1 pm (today is Monday) informing her this and explicitly requested her to let me know if it was okay.

I've not heard back from her, yet. I understand that some people choose not to see work related emails over weekends. But I'm inclined to believe that she has seen the email but forgot to reply (which is quite understandable). I wouldn't worry about this in normal circumstances but I need to talk to my current manager as soon as possible and that depends on the reply I get from this COO.

I want to remind her, but

> Hi XYZ, please respond to my last email.

sounds rude to me. Should I just copy paste the last email?

**UPDATE 1** : I listened to @Jane and decided to wait until tomorrow. But I got a reply late evening. A few emails were exchanged back and forth. Here's the summary -

She told me that it was very unprofessional of me to commit to a date I was not ready to honour. I apologised to her to begin with & explained that I gave them the date because I'd seen some cases where other people in my office were released in a very short period. But my current employer has caught me in technicalities and if I don't serve the full official notice period, I will have to pay a large penalty. I didn't dare to ask her if they'd be willing to pay that on my behalf. She said she needs to discuss the situation internally and they'll let me know their decision by tomorrow.

In short, I messed up. Bigtime.

**UPDATE 2** : I kept the job! My joining bonus took a significant hit. But I'm just happy to have salvaged the job. My guess is that a fresh interview process might have taken the same amount of time in which I'd be able start there (this time for real :P).

Thanks a lot *The Workplace!* You were a big help. You cannot imagine how palpable my relief is. I really didn't want to lose this.

**Lesson Learned** : NEVER promise your new employer a date which is earlier than the official notice period of your current organization.

Comment: Wait... did you accept a new job and promise a start date, but then let your old boss talk you into staying another month when you gave your notice?

Comment: If you're unsure whether "*please respond*" is rude I can only imagine what your original mail contained. As the answers below state this isn't a simple FYI but something that employers can pull offers over. If you're starting in the next few **days**, why on earth did you think this wouldn't warrant a phone call?

Comment: @J... it's not like that. I had expected to be released from the current company much sooner, so I had given my new employer a date accordingly.  But there is more dependency on me currently than even I realized. It was an honest mistake on my part.

Comment: @RodrikTheReader Well... if it looks like a duck...  I mean, unless you have a clear contractual obligation to give what we can best infer is six weeks of notice, and unless you really don't care about having the new job, then I would probably strongly reconsider your decision to play to the wishes of your old company.  If there was that much dependency on you, then it's really your manager's problem to deal with.

Comment: @RodrikTheReader: You should explain honestly exactly what happened. Note that you might lose the offer either way.

Comment: What does her being a COO have to do with it?  If I wanted to send a reminder email to someone that I was still awaiting their reply, it would be the same regardless of their title/position. Treat everyone with the same amount of respect whether they're the COO or cleaning the toilets.

Comment: @AdamRice You are right. But I'm on the back foot in this situation. It was my mistake that I gave the company a date on which I would not be able to join. I'm really looking forward to this new job & I didn't want to make the situation worse by letting them think that I have a casual approach towards my new employer. Hence the trepidation.

Comment: For any similar situation with your end date in the future, always give whatever the contractual maximum is unless you've already negotiated a shorter period.  If your soon to be ex employer frequently lets people go sooner you can add that you might be able to start sooner; but never make a promise that is contingent on someone else for you to be able to keep.  Especially when that person is likely to be upset with you.

Comment: +1 for the update. In the future, don't have discussions like these per email. You can send off an initial email which briefly describes the situation, lists your number, asks when and at which number you should call her.

Comment: @RodrikTheReader from my understanding it's always easier to say, "I'll be available 1 month earlier than expected" rather than, "I actually won't be available for 1 more month".

Comment: @RodrikTheReader, don't worry, they don't get right resource that easily and available to join immediately. So, they only try to put pressure and show their frustration by saying they will come back in a day. They will definitely give you some cautious words, but will agree to wait for a month.

Comment: If I was the COO, I would have sat on that email until I decided whether the next candidate in line might have been a better choice.

Comment: Well, you did screw up, but to the COO it probably makes you look good, since all the other employees got the axe and they decided to keep you longer :) So look on the bright side.

Comment: 'I will have to pay a large penalty' why? They need to pay you out for the time you work, but I'm not aware of any scenario in which you legally need to pay them.

Comment: @krmanish007: I think the bigger question isn't "Can we get someone else on shorter notice?" (to which you're right, the answer is probably "no"), but rather "Can we still trust and rely on this person?"

Comment: You may want to elaborate on the "technicalities" part.  This might be important.

Comment: "professionalism" probably isn't the tag you're looking for ;).

Comment: The day companies workload will reduce, they will take no time giving notice, so for me professionalism doesn't matter too much. Its just give and take or rather demand and supply.

Comment: "NEVER promise your new employer a date which is earlier than the official notice period of your current organization." Did you really need stackexchange to understand this? The title is completely misleading. The COO wasn't the problem here.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A better way of wording it would be to reply to the previous email you sent to her with something like:

> Hi XYZ,
>
> I was wondering if you have had a chance to take a look at the email I sent on Friday.  I'm sorry to push, I just need to have confirmation so that I can work with my current manager as soon as possible.
>
> Regards.
>   RodrikTheReader

I understand the urgency, but you do need to give her a chance to not only read but to act on the information you have given her.  I'd recommend waiting until tomorrow (Tuesday) morning and then sending off the above.

Answer (score 66):

You should pick up the phone and call her, or someone else at the company if you cannot reach her.

However, you should also make it very clear that this is blunder on your part, and that you are willing to be very flexible and find a solution that will work for the company.

Answer (score 8):

**In general, patience is a virtue.** Even if the email is somewhat urgent you need to allow at least 1–2 working days for a response. People are busy and that especially counts for COOs. While a lot of people do read their work related emails over the weekend it should not be brought into account, instead you need to make effort on you part to communicate during the week.

**If the email is urgent you can send a read receipt with it (not recommended, but worth mentioning).** This will notify you when the person confirms that they have read the email. Note that when using read receipts they can still read it and choose not to notify you. Read receipts can also be considered rude by some people.

If you have not received a response within 1–2 working days then you should call the person being contacted. Sending a second email within such a short amount of time might come of as rude to some people but calling wont. Calling shows that you are serious about working with them.

**However, in your case I would call today (Monday).** You said that you are expected to start within the next few days so even waiting one day can be too long.

*Take this next part with a bit of salt...*

Technically if your old employer already knew that you would be leaving in a few days then they should not expect you to stay longer. They may *ask* but they can not *expect* it. So if it is not completely OK with the new company you need to tell the old employer **no**.

**Update:** You learned a valuable lesson. Just because previous employees where released on a short basis does not mean you will get the same treatment. When looking to switch jobs you need to *first* make sure until when you are contractually subjected to work *before* promising any date to your new employer.

Comment: Counter-opinion: do not use read receipts. They are considered rude by a lot of people. "most people won['t deliberately not send a read receipt]" maybe not most, but potentially a lot. And even if you do receive a read receipt, it doesn't actually help you.

Comment: I reflected on my suggestion to use read receipts and changed my meaning. I have become accustomed to receiving them over time but I remember how rude I found them in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Start your new job when you said you would and work as a consultant for your old job, should that be allowed. Many people who were important to their previous employer have gone this route to aid the transition (rather than delay the inevitable). You sticking around longer at the place you are leaving isn't going to help as much as anyone imagines and the world will go on without you.

Also consider that you sent the first email on a Friday in the summer and it's merely Monday.