# If and how to remind my future boss?

Tags: professionalism, job-offer, email

In June I bought a laptop from one place and needed to visit the place multiple times due to getting defected Chargers or PSUs. After some times the salesman (boss of company, company consists of 4-5 people) was like oh you seem pretty tech savvy, do you want to come to work to us (or something like) I, of course, said yes, since I am a big IT guy or "Poweruser", but I am also 14, what makes me in a lower position.

In my age, there aren't many jobs, if there is, they are pretty bad, but in an area I like and the will to make that offer is really good opportunity for me. Since in Estonia, for the employer, it is really hard (paperwork wise) to pay out money to >18 aged people, then I even offered to do it for free, since I would get lots out of it anyway, but he denied the offer.

Since they have more clients in autumn, he told me that he will contact me in August. On the first week of August Thursday after closing hours (so he would get it as first on Friday) I sent an email asking "is the offer still there" (sounds a bit different in Estonian, also between that and June were a bit more emails ~25) Then he told me that they would pretty much definitely need my position to filled (encouraging, that the offer is still there) and he will contact me in the middle of August. (also he's and others emails are bombarded with emails every day since people contact them..)

I definitely don't want to in any way turn the offer down, but the end of the middle week of August is soon here and in case he doesn't answer anytime soon, I think I might need to send him an email. Now that will become a small problem since I don't want to annoy him with more. **So if the time goes by, should I even remind and how?**

Also, I would see people mark this as a possible duplicate of [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/96250/how-do-i-politely-remind-the-coo-of-a-company-to-respond-to-my-previous-email), but I think my situation is a bit (more than bit) different.

My formatting and grammar may not be right since English is not my native language.

[About the other duplicate:](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p) I am the only candidate so in my situation it doesn't apply to wait because another candidate not responded and wait. But I am not excluding it totally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @SaggingRufus I haven't had any interviews or such.

Comment: @ChaosisaLadder It is a bit of a risk, but sadly the phone audio is too shit (seriusly), that I just can't (normally when calling you need to ask 3 times over), i have he's both work and personal - as suffix in he's emails

Comment: @KristoferVesi I think the same logic applies

Comment: @ChaosisaLadder I have 2 homes, from 1 I can get there in 20 min, from other 50 min. Are you thinking that I just pop up and do some talk magic?

Comment: @SaggingRufus Agree, but I still think it is a bit different, I think this will be fast anyway, then I can delete it, you can mark it as duplicate, tough I still think it is a bit diffent, give it couple of hours.

Comment: can you explain how it is different?

Comment: @SaggingRufus Don't sweat it.  If its a duplicate the community will close it.

Comment: @SaggingRufus in the Org. question, edited it

Answer (score 5):

No you should not E-mail him.

His business is working with people.  He was interested in you because of the way you interacted with him as much if not more than your knowledge.

You need to go into the store to see him.  You can go in and just wait for him to not be busy before you approach him.  Then talk to him and interact and let him know how you are looking forward to working with him.  I would be going in at least once a week, until he either hires you or asks you to stop.  If he asks you to stop coming in then you know its time to look for another position.

Comment: Really hope, that I get an email back, since I still think that going there without no notice feels wrong, since they have 1 common room, 1 back room only and the discussion wouldn't be as much private... In the end I will wait for the end of this week and if no response, I will need to pick something from here, probably the visit one.

Comment: @KristoferVesi - It doesn't need to be private for your purposes.  I understand you are uncomfortable doing it but you are demonstrating the skills he is looking for by doing it.  Don't interrupt or get in the way of his other business.  But don't be afraid to let someone else see that you are in there looking for work.  There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: You & @ChaosisaLadder I think it is a bit unclear, but the job is for more tech repair/swap than sales, but it may be part of it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> So if the time goes by, should I even remind and how?

Yes, you should ask about the opportunity if your truly interested in it. 
 Normally in these scenarios I would suggest a phone conversation.  Since the phone quality there is crap, your only other viable option is to pay him a visit.

Based on what you have shared regarding your conversations, I don't see paying him a visit as a big deal:  He either will want to talk further with you about the opportunity, or he won't.  The only way to know is to ask, and this is best done as part of a conversation anyway versus an email.

I would start the conversation by reviewing your other conversations, then I would ask if he was serious about considering you for the position, and if so what are the next steps?

Comment: so go there and be like hey what about the job?

Comment: @KristoferVesi Answer updated.

Comment: Well basically any time I have been there have been problems, it may seem weird. And almost all other conversations are basically hey I didn't figure it out myself, any advice? -Come & visit....

Comment: @KristoferVesi Try to keep the conversation on the potential position.  If the person changes the topic, politely change it back.  It may be difficult to do, but remember that will be the whole reason for the visit.

Comment: Well it is 73 mins till closing, and probably he's not there at this time. I am now thinking of sending an email asking to "meet up" for example in the shop and discuss about "the job"

Comment: That *may* work.  But with the volume of emails you mentioned, don't be surprised if you don't get a response.

Comment: I will scrub up a draft, but about the volume I mean that he sees every one, but if it isn't something that he needs to then he doesn't repsond. The SE is not suggesting to auto move this disc to chat, I would agree. Move it if you agreee too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63853/discussion-between-kristofer-vesi-and-chaos-is-a-ladder).